# Pass value from mouse Pressed event to mouse Dragged event

Tags: javafx

the purpose of this function is to make my button able to be dragged inside a pane, but the initial dragging position is not correct; I need those 2 mouse x y point to make it correct, but i cant pass them in to my dragging event;
I know that I can create my own button class that extends and override the generic Button class; however, is there any other way to solve this problem?

```
 public void editTable(Button mytablebutton){


        Button table = mytablebutton;


        double mouseClickPointX;
        double mouseClickPointY;



        table.setOnMousePressed(new EventHandler<MouseEvent>() {

               @Override
               public void handle(MouseEvent e) { 
                System.out.println( e.getX());
                System.out.println(e.getY());
                // mouseClickPointX = e.getX();     --> This is the thing i want to do, but cant
                // mouseClickPointY = e.getY();     --> This is the thing i want to do, but cant
               }
           });

        table.setOnMouseDragged(new EventHandler<MouseEvent>() {

               @Override
               public void handle(MouseEvent e) { 
                  double x=table.getBoundsInParent().getMinX();  
                  double y=table.getBoundsInParent().getMinY();  
                  table.setLayoutX(x+e.getX()-mouseClickPointX());
                  table.setLayoutY(y+e.getY()-mouseClickPointY());

               }

           });                   



     }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't do this exactly the way you are trying because you can't access non-final variables inside an anonymous class.

The fix is to use a final reference to a mutable object for the data. A `javafx.beans.property.DoubleProperty` works well:

```
final DoubleProperty mouseClickPointX = new SimpleDoubleProperty();
```

Then in the `mousePressed` handler do

```
mouseClickPointX.set(e.getX());
```

and in the `mouseDragged` handler do

```
table.setLayoutX(x+e.getX()-mouseClickPointX.get());
```

Do the same for y, obviously.
You can also use an `ObjectProperty<Point2D>`, or just create your own simple mutable Point class.

Answer (score 0):

A bit late I know, but for anyone else with a similar problem.

You should try declaring the shared variables static.

I think the problem is that, because mouseDragged comes from the MouseMotionListener interface and mousePressed comes from MouseListener, the class is added twice as separate objects to the pane, via addMouseListener and addMouseMotionListener.  Declaring a variable static makes it a common variable shared by all objects constructed from the class.